# How to display a Map<String, Object> in jsf

Tags: jsf

I have a method  returning `Map<String, Object>`
and in my Object :

```
private ObjectName objectName;
private List<> list1;
private List<> list2;
```

my method:  `Map<String, Object> getInfoCli()`

how I can display it in JSF?

I try:

```
<c:forEach items="${accountController.infoCli.entrySet().toArray()}" var="info">
        <p><h:outputText value="#{info.key}"/></p>
        <c:forEach value="#{info.value}" var="infoVal">
                <ui:include src="">
              <ui:param name="beneficiaire"     value="#{infoVal.objectName }"/>
              <ui:param name="prelCBInfos"      value="#{infoVal.list1}"/>
              <ui:param name="aboPrelInfos"     value="#{infoVal.list2}"/>
            </ui:include>
        </c:forEach>                
 </c:forEach>
```

Comment: Ask yourself: How would you do it in plain Java? Also with a nested for loop? How is that possible on `Object`? It's not different in JSF.

Comment: @BalusC i know it s not list to us forEach  put i dont know how ?

Comment: `#{info.value}` is your `Object` already. No need to loop over it. Remove the second `<c:forEach>`.

Comment: @BalusC I know how  #{info.value.objectName} thank you